# avoid textview growing when cursor is on the same line, textview on top keyboard, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uiviewanimation

I am doing a quick reply by adding `textView` on top keyboard. I am doing the following to re-calculate the height of the container which is containing a `textView` inside.
This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{
    NSLog(@"inputView is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.inputView.frame));
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(self.inputView.frame.size.width, self.inputView.frame.size.height);

    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.inputView.font.pointSize] };

    CGSize textSize = [self.inputView.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                                 attributes:stringAttributes
                                                    context:nil].size;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect r = self.frame;
                     r.origin.y -= ceil(textSize.height);       // use ceil function to avoid we have a gap between textview and kboard during transition
                     r.size.height += ceil(textSize.height);
                     self.frame = r;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
                 }
     ];

    return YES;
}
```

However, the issue is that the `textView` keeps growing like below
[image]

Are there any ways to avoid this? I just want `textView` to grow when *text* enters the second line or when you hit return.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
                         if (self.myTextView.contentSize.height > frame.size.height) {
                             CGFloat offset = self.myTextView.contentSize.height - frame.size.height;
                             frame.size.height = self.myTextView.contentSize.height;
                             frame.origin.y -= ceil(offset);
                         }
                         self.myTextView.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         /* completion code here */
                     }
     ];
    return YES;
}
```

You should always check if the `contentSize` is *greater than* exising `frame Height`.
That was why your `textView` kept growing.
Hope this solves your problem !